# Extract font-family and font-weight of @font-face from a CSS file

Tags: php, regex

I have a function that loops through all CSS files in directory and looks for `@font-face`.
if any `@font-face` block found, I want to extract `font-family` and `font-weight` from it.
the code below is what I've done so far:

```
function get_local_fonts() {
    $output = array();
    $path_to_search = trailingslashit(get_template_directory());
    foreach(glob_recursive($path_to_search . '*.css') as $file) {
        $content = file_get_contents($file);
        preg_match('/(\@font-face)([^}]+)(\})/', $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

        if (!empty($matches)) {
            preg_match('/(font-family:)([^;]*)/', $matches[2][0], $font_family, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
            preg_match('/(font-weight:)([^;]*)/', $matches[2][0], $font_weight, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

            $output[] = array(
                'file_path' => $file,
                'font-family' => trim($font_family[2][0]),
                'font-weight' => array(trim($font_weight[2][0])),
            );
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

this `preg_match('/(\@font-face)([^}]+)(\})/', $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);` returns every CSS file that includes `@font-face { ... }`

my function works well with CSS files that only have one match for `@font-face` but let say if there are 4 matches for @font-face in a single CSS file my function only adds one of them.
**for example (css file content):**

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: "din";
    src: url("din-webfont.eot");
    src: url("din-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),  url("din-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("din-webfont.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face
{
    font-family: "din";
    src: url("din_bold-webfont.eot");
    src: url("din_bold-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("din_bold-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("din_bold-webfont.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I want to get output like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [font-family] => 'din'
            [font-weight] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 'normal',
                    [1] => 'bold'
                )

        )
)
```

Note that there might be `@font-face` with same `font-family` but different `font-weight`.

**for conclusion:**
 
How can I loop through All CSS files that contains

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: something;
    font-weight: something;
}
```

and extract `font-family` and `font-weight` from them?

Comment: Ok, I think I had to use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`... still if you have any suggestion to improve my regex pattern that would be nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
$fontregex = '~@font-face[^}]*?font-family:\s*"([^"]+)"[^}]*?font-weight:\s*([^;]+);[^}]*?font-style:\s*([^;]+);~';
preg_match_all($fontregex, $mycss, $matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

See the output at the bottom of the **[online php demo](http://ideone.com/gIj5bU)**.
You'll have to fan the the result of `$matches` into a final array in a way that suits you.

Currently, here is the structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => @font-face
{
    font-family: "din";
    src: url("din-webfont.eot");
    src: url("din-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),  url("din-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("din-webfont.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
            [1] => din
            [2] => normal
            [3] => normal
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => @font-face
{
    font-family: "din";
    src: url("din_bold-webfont.eot");
    src: url("din_bold-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("din_bold-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("din_bold-webfont.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
            [1] => din
            [2] => bold
            [3] => normal
        )

)
```